# Post simple form with ajax and Json

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to get a form to work with Ajax and json but can't seem to work it out:(
If anyone can help out I'd really appreciate it! Been reading so many different tutorials but not getting it right.

- In my index.php I have a form with only a image that works as a button.
- Then in another file (allFunctions.php) I have a class. Within that class I have a function called
  `giveCandy()` which is connected to the button.
- Then I have a js file that I'm now trying to get working with this. But When I click the button the page still refreshes and I get the value `true` printed out.

UPDATE: Still problem with the page refreshing...

The index.php file:

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST"> 
<input type="hidden" name="candy" />
<input type="image" id="button_candy" class="four columns" src="views/img/candy.png"/>
</form>
```

Then in my functions file:

```
function giveCandy ()
    {
        if ( isset($_POST['candy']))
        {   

        $db = Database::getInstance();
        $classUser = new user();
        $userId = $classUser->getUserData($_SESSION['id']);
        $user = $userId['id'];

        $candyPiece = 10;

        $query = $db->prepare("SELECT fullness, lastfed FROM userdata WHERE id = ?");
        $query->bindValue(1, $user);

        $query->execute();
        $data = $query->fetch();

        $newFullness = $candyPiece + $data['fullness'];

        try
            {
        $query = $db->prepare("UPDATE userdata SET fullness = $newFullness, lastfed = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE id = ?");
        $query->bindValue(1, $user);

        $query->execute();
        //$this->calculateFullness();
        echo json_encode($query);
            }
        catch (PDOException $e)
            {
                echo 'Sorry iti could not eat at this time';        
            }
        }
    }
```

Then the js file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#button_candy').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: $(this).serialize(), // your formdata (this refers to the form element)
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) { // data is what your allFunctions.php php echos
                $('#query').fadeOut(function () {
                    $('#query').html(data).fadeIn();
                });
                console.log('Ajax request returned successfully.');
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('Ajax request failed: ' + textStatus + ', ' + errorThrown);
            },
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Try `exit()` after you `json_encode` the result in php file. Also, check our console if the response is in proper json format.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I just tried exit() but then the page gets all blank with true printed... I´m not sure how to use the console:(

Comment: Why would the page get blank? It means code is not reaching $.ajax. Try debugging that. Anyways https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console is essential for debugging JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

allFunctions.php:

```
if ($_POST['candy']) {
    allFunctions::giveCandy();
}

class allFunctions {

    static function giveCandy ()
    { 
        $db = Database::getInstance();
        // ....
```

Js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#button_candy').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '../model/allFunctions.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: $(this).serialize(), // your formdata (this refers to the form element)
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) { // data is what your allFunctions.php php echos
                $('#result').fadeOut(function () {
                    $('#result').html(data).fadeIn();
                });
                console.log('Ajax request returned successfully.');
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('Ajax request failed: ' + textStatus + ', ' + errorThrown);
            },
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer! I tried changing this but I still get the same result. Should I change this: data: 'function = giveCandy()', to this: data: $(this).serialize()  ?

Comment: Yes, thats why i wrote it above... ;) The data parameter exprects a key:value array like in POST or GET.

Comment: Hm it´s not working, still the page refresh and it says True printed at the top of the page. It feels like there is something else wrong here, the values from my query in the function is not suppose to be returned thrue... Also if I change the data parameter like you say how can it find the right method in my class?

Comment: You cannot tell your php script which function to use. The php script just gets called and the parameters you define in data are transmitted as they would be in a nomral POST form. Then your php logic has to decide what to do.

Comment: Still same problem with this code. And now I removed $result and changed echo json_encode($result); to  return json_encode($query); instead and changed in the js file as well. But the page still refresh:(

Comment: Just updated... I`m checking if Post is set inside the giveCandy() function. It should work. I tried putting it above like you said but didn´t work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43220/discussion-between-markus-kottlander-and-lisa)